# Deserializing multiple different derived types

Tags: c#, .net, xml, web-services, deserialization

Running into a bit of an issue here. I have some xml that is coming back from a 3rd party service that looks like this(simplified)

```
<Root>
    <Response>
        <Record></Record>   
    </Response>
    <Response>
        <Record></Record>   
    </Response>
</Root>
```

Each record has the potential to be an object of a different type, and a single xml message could have multiple responses

My classes look something like this

```
public class Response
{
    [XmlElement(typeof(DerivedRecord1))]
    [XmlElement(typeof(DerivedRecord2))]
    public BaseRecord Record { get; set;}
}

public class BaseRecord { }
public class DerivedRecord1 : BaseRecord { }
public class DerivedRecord2 : BaseRecord { }
```

When I look at the Record object after it has been deserialized, it comes back as null for both responses.

Now, when I use the XmlInclude element on my base class instead the XmlElement attribute on the property, the Record is of the base class and not the derived type.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you know what type of response you will get with each request?  If you do, you should check out [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/) for getting the right DTO per the right request, even if they all request from the same service. SS will do the deserialization for you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I have quite a bit invested already in using the default classes-to-xml. The 3rd party webservice I am connecting to doesn't have a proper wsdl either, it only accepts a string of xml and returns a string of xml.